# Make files for a programmatic UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I made a `UINavigationController`, and I have it working just fine but I need to work with it now. I need files that are in sync with the controller. I build everything programatically.

How do I get these files set up?

**AppDelegate.h:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *rvc;
```

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:126/255 blue:233/255 alpha:1]];
    [self.window addSubview:[self.navigationController view]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.rvc animated:YES];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: in modern iOS programming you should set window's `rootViewController` property as opposed to adding view controller's view as a subview: `self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIViewController` subclass and make `rvc` property have type of that class. After that you can write your logic in the created subclass.

Proper `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:126/255 blue:233/255 alpha:1]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;

    self.rvc = [[<your_class_name> alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.rvc animated:YES];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Make a file called rvc that subclasses from UIViewController?

Comment: you can call the subclass whatever you want :) Just change the `rvc` property to that type: `@property (strong, nonatomic) <your_new_class> *rvc;`. And also when you actually create the `rvc` object, you should write `self.rvc = [[<your_new_class> alloc] init];`

Comment: I created the file, then changed it to rvc *rViewController. To test, I do an NSLog when the viewDidLoad in rvc. It doesn't log. @kambala

Comment: Oh whoops! forgot the allocinit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's simple you can apply this code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255 green:126/255 blue:233/255 alpha:1]];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```